# Serialize QList<CustomClass>

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am working on a serializer with Qt.
I use `QObject`'s `Q_PROPERTY` to be able to use `QMetas` classes.

Classes are like :

```
class Person : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString firstname READ firstname WRITE setFirstName)
    Q_PROPERTY(int age READ age WRITE setAge)

public:
    Person();
    Person(const Person &other);
    Person &operator=(const Person &other);

    /* READ & WRITE accessors are implemented */
};


class Enterprise : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Person owner READ owner WRITE setOwner)
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<Person> employees READ employees WRITE setEmployees)

public:
    Enterprise();
    Enterprise(const Enterprise &other);
    Enterprise &operator=(const Enterprise &other);

    /* READ & WRITE accessors are implemented */
};
```

Both class and the list are declared with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` and `qRegisterMetaType`.

Then I want to save data with:

```
QVariantMap serializer(const QObject &object)
{
    const QMetaObject *mo = object.metaObject();
    QVariantMap varmap;
    for(int pid = 0; pid < mo->propertyCount(); ++pid)
    {
        QMetaProperty mp = mo->property(pid);
        QString pName = QString::fromLatin1(mp.name());
        if(pName.toLower() == "objectname")
            continue;

        QVariant vdata = mp.read(&object);

        if(mp.type() == QVariant::UserType)
        {
            int metaTypeId = QMetaType::type(mp.typeName());
            if(metaTypeId != QMetaType::UnknownType)
            {
                void *data = QMetaType::create(metaTypeId, vdata.data());
                QObject *subobject = static_cast<QObject*>(data);

                vdata = serializer(*subobject);

                QMetaType::destroy(metaTypeId, data);
                data = 0;
            }
        }
        varmap.insert(pName, vdata);
    }
    return varmap;
}
```

It works for everything except for the property with a list. This sound normal as long as `QList` is not a `QObject`. So how can I do ?

Comment: How do you have `Person` class objects as properties if it can't have a copy constructor?

Comment: In fact, it does. I just didn't copy here. Both class have default and copy constructor and '=' and '==' operators.